# JavaFX: ListView: SetId from ListCell with ID from POJO

Tags: rest, listview, javafx

I'm trying to develop a little contact managment tool with mongoDB, restful-webservice and javaFX on the client site. The restful-webservice is finsihed and now I'm try develop the client.

I use the following path to get information for a single contact:

**/contacts/entity/{uid}**

where {uid} is the objectID from the single contact in mongodb.

If i want to set this pathparam from my client i have to get the object id. I thought it would be nice if the id from a listcell is the objectid from a single object so that I can use *ListCell*.getId() to add the pathparam while clicking on a listCell.

Now my questin is: How can is do this, so that the objectId from a returned object is used for the id for a single listCell?

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: you wan to set listcell with data from a POJO class?